# PostgreSQL 12 partition join slow queries

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I have an issue with slow query when joining two partitioned tables. This is a query used to test
speed:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS erc_full_count
FROM event_record AS erc
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT id, event_record_id FROM rlc_data AS rld
      WHERE rld.active is true and rld.deleted is FALSE
      AND  (NULL::BOOLEAN is NULL OR rld.group_event=NULL::BOOLEAN)
      AND (NULL::TIMESTAMP IS NULL OR rld.created_time >= NULL::TIMESTAMP)
      AND (NULL::TIMESTAMP IS NULL OR rld.created_time <= NULL::TIMESTAMP)
) AS sub_rld
ON erc.id = sub_rld.event_record_id
 WHERE erc.deleted is FALSE
 AND (-1::BIGINT = -1 OR erc.device_id=-1::BIGINT)
 AND (-1::BIGINT = -1 OR erc.module_serial_number=-1::BIGINT)
 AND (NULL::TIMESTAMP IS NULL OR erc.record_time >= NULL::TIMESTAMP)
 AND (NULL::TIMESTAMP IS NULL OR erc.record_time <= NULL::TIMESTAMP)
 AND erc.active is TRUE;
```

```
The main issue is with NESTED LOOP because it lasts more than 40 seconds. 
This is a response that I got from database:
```

```
   https://pastebin.com/VQpnTLYS
```

Comment: JSON format is good for parsers but not for eyes.

Comment: I didn't look at the plan, but did you set `enable_partitionwise_join` to `on`?

Comment: Sorry for JSON formatting but I was using "https://planchecker.cfapps.io/" to visualize AND yes tested with enable_partitionwise_join = true and false -> when disabled it is a bit faster but result above is with enable_partitionwise_join = false